# linq how would i order this statement

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

as you can see, i'm trying to perform multiple order by statements at the end of the statement.  my results are not coming back correct.

```
var query = 
    (from x in workloadDetail
    group x by new { x.titleOrder, x.httitle } into sortedData                        
    select new WorkloadSummary()
    {
    httitle = sortedData.Key.httitle,
    totalHrs = sortedData.Sum(x => x.totalHrs),
    totalDol = sortedData.Sum(x => x.totalDol),
    titleOrder = sortedData.Key.titleOrder
    }).OrderBy(x => x.httitle).OrderByDescending(x => x.totalHrs);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `ThenByDescending` method to apply secondary sorting in descending order.

```
.OrderBy(x => x.httitle).ThenByDescending(x => x.totalHrs);
```

Answer (score 5):

If you are chaining multiple `OrderBy()` queries, you need to use `ThenBy()` and `ThenByDescending()` for subsequent properties for them to be applied in the proper order :

```
.OrderBy(x => x.httitle).ThenByDescending(x => x.totalHrs);
```

Comment: i was 9 sec fast :P